# Time limit exceeded on the code: Check If a String Contains All Binary Codes of Size K

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, sliding-window

I'm trying to solve LeetCode problem [1461. Check If a String Contains All Binary Codes of Size K](https://leetcode.com/problems/check-if-a-string-contains-all-binary-codes-of-size-k/description/):

> Given a binary string `s` and an integer `k`, return `true` *if every binary code of length* `k` *is a substring of* `s`. Otherwise, return `false`.

### Thought process

Make a list of all possible binary strings of length `k` (named it `binary`). Then iterate through the string with sliding windows, and for every window check if that exists in the list called `binary`. If the list is empty it means it satisfied all possible strings. If it's not empty that means it didn't include all the possible binary codes and will return false.

### Code

```
class Solution(object):
    def hasAllCodes(self, s, k):
        """
        :type s: str
        :type k: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if k > len(s):
            return False
        binary = [""]
        for i in range(k):
            N = len(binary)
            for i in range(N):
                a = binary.pop(0)
                binary.append(a + "0")
                binary.append(a + "1")

        n=len(s)
        i=j=0
        sSoFar=""
        while j<n:
            sSoFar+=s[j]
            if j>=k-1:
                if sSoFar in binary:
                    binary.remove(sSoFar)
                sSoFar=sSoFar[1:]
                i+=1
            j+=1


        #print(binary)
        return len(binary)==0


solution = Solution()
a = solution.hasAllCodes("00110110", 2) #expected true
print(a)
a = solution.hasAllCodes("0110", 1) #expected true
print(a)
a = solution.hasAllCodes("0110", 2) #expected false
print(a)
a = solution.hasAllCodes("1011110111001001101001110001100111101111010101011100111001110010010001000111010110101110000110101001011100100010100110011101011110001000100010101101011", 20) #expected false
print(a)
```

### Issue

I get a time limited exceeded error on the last test included in above code snippet. What should I improve on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list `pop(0)` and `remove` methods have a bad time complexity.

It is more efficient to work with a set, and let it be a set of `int` instead of strings. It will also be faster if you start with an *empty* set, and *add* the values to it that you find while scanning the input string.

Keep track of what the *value* is of the k-size "window" you're inspecting in the main loop. When the window slides one position forward, you can easily *update* the value by:

1. multiplying it with 2 to make room for the new digit
2. adding the new digit to it (as either 0 or 1)
3. Dropping the "old" digit, by using a modulo operation (or applying a bit mask)

Then *add* these values to a `set`. You can see from the size of that set whether all binary numbers were collected or not.

Here is a spoiler solution:

> `def hasAllCodes(self, s, k):
>          binary = set()  # Start with empty set.
>          n = len(s)
>          value = int("0" + s[:k-1], 2)  # Avoid error when k=1 and prepad a zero
>          mod = 1 << k   # This is 2**k, but as an integer operation
>          for digit in s[k-1:]:
>              value = (value * 2 + int(digit)) % mod  # Slide the window
>              binary.add(value)
>              if len(binary) == mod:  # We found all binary numbers?
>                  return True
>          return False`

Comment: i have been reading this over for a few times and when you say keep track of value you mean the number of the binary string in the window? for eg s = "00110110" and k=2 so we keep track of what "00" represent (0) or '01" represent (1) as we go through windows and put that in the set? i am sorry if its basic

Comment: Yes, exactly, the integer value of the binary representation. For instance, if k= 4, and we already know "0011" represents 3, then we *know* that the next window will represent either 6 or 7: we just need to read the next "0" or "1" to know which of the two.

Comment: it finally makes sense, thank you. great way of dealing with the problem

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to just use a set comprehension to get all the distinct substrings of length `k` and check the size of that set.

```py
class Solution(object):
    def hasAllCodes(self, s, k):
        return len({s[i:i+k] for i in range(len(s) - k + 1)}) == 1 << k
```

Comment: This answer is correct and provides a good alternative.